# How to Clear Input Form After Click Submit

Tags: javascript, forms

I've tried many ways from several threads but to no avail.
I have form code like this:

```
                <div id="fVoucher">
                <form id="myForm" name="login" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post" $(if chap-id) onSubmit="return doLogin()"
                    $(endif)>
                    <input type="hidden" name="dst" value="$(link-orig)" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />

                    <p class="px-3 pt-3 pb-1 font-semibold text-gray-500 text-md">Voucher Login</p>
                    <div class="mx-3 ">
                        <label class="flex flex-row justify-between space-x-2 justify-items-center">
                            <input name="username" type="text" value="$(username)" id="userVoucher" oninput="getValue()"
                                class="block w-full h-10 px-3 bg-white border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-opacity-70 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
                                placeholder="Voucher" onpaste="return false;" />
                            <input name="password" type="hidden" id="passVoucher"
                                class="block w-full h-10 px-3 bg-white border-gray-300 rounded-md shadow-sm bg-opacity-70 focus:border-indigo-300 focus:ring focus:ring-indigo-200 focus:ring-opacity-50"
                                placeholder="Password" />
                            <button id="btn_submit" type="submit"
                                class="px-3 font-semibold text-gray-500 rounded-md shadow-md bg-gradient-to-br from-yellow-200 to-yellow-400">Login</button>
                        </label>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

This is the script I tried to remove the input form after clicking submit. But it didn't work.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var reset = function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('form')[0].reset();
    },3000);
}
$('.btn_submit').on('click', function(){
    reset();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Remove the event handller on the button (ie. all of that jQuery you posted) and add `$('form')[0].reset();` as the last line of `doLogin()`

Answer (score 0):

When resetting a form, you have to target the `form` element.

You can do it inline like below.

```
<button type="submit" onclick="this.form.reset();">Login</button>
```

Or, Inside a onClick event handler.

```
document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
```

Or, (jQuery)

```
$('#myForm').trigger("reset");
```

Instead of clearing the form on 'Login' button click, I think it's better to have a separate button like 'Clear' / 'Reset' to reset the form. It's much more cleaner in this way.

Comment: jQuery core does not have a reset() method

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks. I've corrected my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting against a class and not an ID:

```
$('.btn_submit').on('click', function(){
    reset();
});
```

Note:

```
<button id="btn_submit" type="submit"
```